# Is it "transfer onto x", "transfer to x" or "transfer on x"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is it "transfer onto x", "transfer to x" or "transfer on x"? I am not sure what is the correct way to say transfer something from y to z. What if the something is an image on a flat surface?

For example:

> He transferred the dot onto the left screen using his mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal usage, things are transferred from one place to another.

> They transferred the load from the truck to my car.

Again in normal usage, "onto" would be used in cases where what is being stressed is the idea of lifting.

> They transferred the load onto the roof of my car.

In mathematical and technical usage, "transfer onto" frequently carries the sense of being transferred to a specific place rather than a general place.

> They transferred the image to a page open to everyone on the network.

This means it is somewhere on the page, but is not more specific.

> They transferred the new image onto the page's old image.

This means the new image was superimposed onto a previous image. The transfer went to a specific place.